# How do I put <td> tag and <div> tags inline?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

See the right side of the [image](http://www.flickr.com/photos/37280036@N04/9610941325/).

In the table, under Tonage Bytes , I want this progress bar to be alongside(inline) to the data,ie along with 929.3.

For reference see this [image](http://www.flickr.com/photos/37280036@N04/9610942273/). I want exactly the same layout.

Currently they both are in different lines. So how can I adjust them inline.

```
<tr>
    <td>Arts and Entertainment</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1.03</td>
    <td>929.3
        <div class="progress">
            <div class="bar" style="width: 60%; height = 20px"></div>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: `height=20px` isn't valid CSS (use `height:20px`). That may be preventing the suggestions from working.

Comment: nice catch. but it isnt working still.  Though it leaves some spave for the progress bar, but unable to show it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume, you just need to assign the following CSS:

```
.progress {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
}
```

`display: inline-block`, however, is not supported by some older browsers ([see MDN, e.g.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display#Browser_compatibility)).

[**Example Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/k2nRs/3/)

Comment: Tried with `inline-block` by customizing the bootstrap css file but the progress bar disappears.

Comment: @user1162512 Updated answer and added a example fiddle.

Comment: Perfect!!! Thanks. But, can you explain briefly why it is necessary to give some content inside the inner div?

Comment: Infact, removing spaces doesnt effect the code. The main catch was `width: 100px;` . Thanks

Comment: @user1162512 You're right. I just c/p an error of yours, which made it fail. In your code it says `height = 20px`, which should be `height: 20px`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `<span>` instead of `<div>`. By default, `<span>` is inline. Alternatively, you can set the css option `display: inline;` or `display: inline-block;` in your `style` attribute

Comment: Tried with both `span`, and `inline-block` and `inline` but the progress bar disappears with all the options tried.

Comment: probably because they are inline and the column is not large enough